# Loop Object from a single Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, object

im sending a Json Array from Activity A to Activity B, and i want to populate that Json Array into Spinner in Activity B. but when i Log the json array from Activity A, the data becomes a single object "NVAKSINATOR" :

> [{"NVAKSINATOR":"[{"NVAKSINATOR":"20800"},{"NVAKSINATOR":"0"},{"NVAKSINATOR":"77350"},{"NVAKSINATOR":"51750"},{"NVAKSINATOR":"30000"},{"NVAKSINATOR":"51500"},{"NVAKSINATOR":"25750"},{"NVAKSINATOR":"30900"}]"}]

i want that number like 20800 , 0 , 77350 to be populated in spinner but i dont know how to loop in single object like that. please help

Comment: loop List<NVAKSINATOR> get number. Then add a new List<String>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

what im doing is, first get the first of index and get the name of my object :

```
JsonArray.getJsonObject(0).getString("NVAKSINATOR");
```

after that, you'll get :

```
[{"NVAKSINATOR":"20800"},
 {"NVAKSINATOR":"0"},
 {"NVAKSINATOR":"77350"},
 {"NVAKSINATOR":"51750"},
 {"NVAKSINATOR":"30000"}, 
 {"NVAKSINATOR":"51500"},
 {"NVAKSINATOR":"25750"},
 {"NVAKSINATOR":"30900"}]
```

last step this is the easiest part, what i do is just looping that array. coz now the length is not 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {  
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();  
    jo = obj.getJSONObject(i); 
    listvaksinator.add(jo.getString("NVAKSINATOR")); 
}
```

and now i got the number inside `NVAKSINATOR` :)